# White screen - MacBook 15” early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, usb, startup, ssd

I have a MacBook Pro 15" early 2011.
It has been slow and full since a long time so I decided to upgrade it with a Samsung 870EVO 2.5 SATA SSD.

Since then, I can't access anything.
I can't boot from a USB (tried 3 USB keys and Lion, Sierra and High Sierra) white screen of death when I boot with the USB after the selection of disk. I can no longer access recovery mode (white screen of death after loading).

When I put in the old disk, I get a sign that I can't get through after loading with the logo. I can't access recovery mode either (white screen of death).

I can't type a command in verbose (with old disk) plus it goes into error too.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it won't boot to a disk with a known working OS (including the original HDD), then it's a hardware fault.

Is it possible that when you installed the SSD, you didn't put everything back correctly, or you actually damaged something?

Realistically, this needs a hands-on inspection. It's too old for an Apple Store, but there might be a local repair shop that does Mac repairs.

(If you haven't already started saving for a replacement, I'd start!)

Comment: I was able to run the apple diagnostic and everything was ok. The old HDD had some issue too with the white screen sometimes since years